# Как наложить аватар пользователя на картинку при приветствии

Tags: discord.py

Видел на многих серверах, когда я захожу на сервер бот отсылает картинку где посередине мой avatar, и снизу текст: Мы рады вас видеть! Вы наш № участник.
Прошу помочь мне, кто знает как сделать такой код.

Answer (score 0):

Дам вам готовый код, вам останется установить библиотеку easy_pil

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    #по данному пути расположите фон
    background = Editor("assets/bg.jpg")
    profile = await load_image_async(str(member.avatar))

    profile = Editor(profile).resize((200, 200)).circle_image()

    square = Canvas((500, 500), "#06FFBF")

    background.paste(profile.image, (300, 30))

    poppins = Font(path =  "assets/arial_bold.ttf").poppins(size=40)
    poppins_small = Font(path =  "assets/ofont.ru_Arial.ttf").poppins(size=30)
    background.text((250, 240), str(member), font=poppins, color="white")

    background.rectangle((0, 290), width=800, height=2, fill="#17F3F6")

    background.text((300, 320), "Welcome!", font=poppins_small, color="white")
    background.text((200, 360), f"Your {member.guild.member_count} member in the server", font=poppins_small, color="white")

    file = File(fp=background.image_bytes, filename="картинка.png")

    await bot.get_channel(int(id канала)).send(member.mention, file=file)
```

Код очень простой, надеюсь я вам помог!